# Can I submit iOS 8 only app to Appstore now that iOS 9 has been released

Tags: ios, ios8, app-store, ios9

I would like to know whether I can release an iOS 8 only app via Xcode 6 now since iOS 9 and Xcode 7 has been released.

P.S Due to business and technical reasons I'm not able to update my app to iOS 9 for now. Thanks.

Comment: If you support iOS version >= 8.0,you

Comment: Right now, probably yes, but not for long

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But previous years using the latest SDK has become mandatory after a few months. I wouldn't rely on being iOS 8-only beyond about February 2016.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen, will accept/update the answer after I upload the app to the Appstore.

Answer (score 0):

You can (currently, as of Oct-2015) still submit apps built with Xcode 6.x the iOS 8 SDK.  But realize that this can not strictly be an "iOS 8 only" app, as Apple will test submitted apps on iOS 9 devices, and reject them if they fails to run on iOS 9 (or whatever is the latest official iOS release).

Comment: so the answer is I can submit, but will be rejected ?

Comment: Have you tested your app on an iOS 9 device?  If it runs OK, it might be approved.

Comment: not yet, need to conduct some development activity for iOS 9 support. Hence I thought I could upload for iOS 8 devices at-least for now.